# Quiz Program at Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, random

Sorry for the disturbance but can you help me in my problem?

I'm new at visual basic programming and everything was fine until our topic shifted to arrays. I tried to understand it's code using Java. (Example: method are called functions.. .)

My prof has given us an exercise to create a Quiz program that asks the user more than 5 questions (in textbox) with choices (in buttons) and computes the score at the end (All just in one form). If the user click an a button it will tell if it's right or wrong and then proceed to change the question along with the choices.

*Required:
- After the user finish the quiz the score will be displayed and there should be a restart button and all the question will be asked again randomly no pattern.
- Try to make functions.

I tried searching the web since yesterday and I still have made no progress at my code.

```
    Public Class Form1
Dim questions(5) As String
Dim answers(5) As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Method/Function for loading the Q&A
    loadQsAndAs()
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub loadQsAndAs()
    'Questions
    questions(0) = "What is 1 + 1?"
    questions(1) = "Who is the first man to walk on the Moon?"
    questions(2) = "What is the name of the main character in the movie: Yes Man!(2007)"
    questions(3) = "If I gave you three apples and you ate two, how many is left?"
    questions(4) = "What do you want in your final grade?"
    questions(5) = "What is the name of the thing(s) that you use whenever you eat?"
    'Answers
    answers(0) = "2"
    answers(1) = "Neil Armstrong"
    answers(2) = "Jim Carrey"
    answers(3) = "1"
    answers(4) = "A 4.0"
    answers(5) = "A Spoon and Fork"

    TextBox1.Text = setTheQuestion()
    Button1.Text = setTheAnswer1()
    Button2.Text = setTheAnswer2()
    Button3.Text = setTheAnswer3()
    Button4.Text = setTheAnswer4()

End Sub

Private Function setTheQuestion() As String
    Dim randomValue As New Random
    Dim randomQ As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim index As Integer

    For i = 0 To 0
        index = randomValue.Next(0, questions.Length)
        randomQ &= questions(index)
    Next
    Return randomQ
End Function

Private Function setTheAnswer1() As String
    Dim randomValue As New Random
    Dim randomAns As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim index As Integer

    For i = 0 To 0
        index = randomValue.Next(0, answers.Length)
        randomAns &= answers(index)
    Next

    Return randomAns
End Function

Private Function setTheAnswer2() As String
    Dim randomValue As New Random
    Dim randomAns As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim index As Integer

    For i = 0 To 0
        index = randomValue.Next(1, answers.Length)
        randomAns &= answers(index)
    Next

    Return randomAns
End Function

Private Function setTheAnswer3() As String
    Dim randomValue As New Random
    Dim randomAns As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim index As Integer

    For i = 0 To 0
        index = randomValue.Next(2, answers.Length)
        randomAns &= answers(index)
    Next

    Return randomAns
End Function

Private Function setTheAnswer4() As String
    Dim randomValue As New Random
    Dim randomAns As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim index As Integer

    For i = 0 To 0
        index = randomValue.Next(3, answers.Length)
        randomAns &= answers(index)
    Next

    Return randomAns
End Function

Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    loadQsAndAs()
End Sub
    End Class
```

My questions are:

- How do I make the questions and my choices in an array to appear randomly whenever the user starts or restarts the program?
- How do I code that the random question will also have the correct answer with the other 3 random answers? (Because mine is just randomizing the answer and it keeps repeating some choices)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a random sequence of numbers when you initialise the quiz, to indicate the sequence of the questions and answers.

Comment: So make a random Integer then connect that integer to my questions and answers? Like a value to make the sequence random?

Comment: When the quiz starts, create a sequence like 4,3,1,2,5,0 at random - using a List, for example. This represents the order your questions are shown in. Then show question 4 first, 3 next, etc.

Comment: "using a List, for example" Do you mean the List(Of T) Class?

Comment: Yes. A List(Of Integer), ideally.

Comment: How do I stop it or how do I put a sentinel to stop it? Also How do I make it loop in just one click? Example: When I click the start a random question in the textbox will appear and also the answers in the buttons and after I clicked a button(answer) it will pop up saying if it is correct or wrong and then proceed to the next random question? Sorry for all of the annoying questions, I'm just really having a hard time at randomizing it.